# Magento upgrade from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.3.4

Tags: php, magento, installation, cpanel, upgrade

i have a website with magento version 1.9.0.1 but now i am seeing allot of unusual activities in my site, someone add ads to site from some where even i changed all passwords etc.

I am now going to upgrade from magento 1.9.0.1 to magento 1.9.3.4 but found no proper roadmap on how to upgrade magento without losing any data of website and setting etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.0.1 from 1.9.3.4

1. Take a backup of the current database and current 1.7 code. place maintenance.flag file inside 1.7 code folder to put website offline.
2. Download latest Magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. Remove all folders and files from your 1.7 code except `maintenance.flag` (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.
4. Now from your 1.7 merge your following custom folders into the 1.9

   - Community `app/code/community`
   - Local `app/code/local`
   - Media
   - your theme or package (`app/design/frontend/default/<your theme>` or `app/design/frontend/<your package>`)
   - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   - copy your custom xml files from `app/etc/modules/` to current `app/etc/modules/`
   - any custom admin theme folder from `adminhtml/default/yourtheme`.
   - copy your custom folders from `adminhtml/default/default/` (1.7) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
   - custom js files if any from `app/js/`.
5. Now go to `app/etc/local.xml`.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6. Remove `maintenance.flag` file and check the site in the browser. it is done.

> Note:- You can also Upgrade CE 1.9.0.1 from 1.9.3.4 through the SSH
> Command, Kindly review this URL:-
> https://astrio.net/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/

Comment: I tried above but is not lock with it.... Seem like everything is giving error and site not running and few folders infact are not same in same place for example app/code/local

Comment: You just follow step by step instruction https://astrio.net/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/

Comment: i did tried but getting following error [26-Aug-2017 13:34:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_GiftMessage_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /home/(hidden)/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 234

Comment: please send me your skype id, will discuss on same or you can contact my skype id..thank you

Comment: Although this might work, I would strongly recommend to upgrade via SSH - for more details have a look at https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/updating-magento1/